# How to retain the value of a text box?

Tags: php, javascript

This is the content on my view page and i want to replace the value from "0" when the monthfunc() is called...the monthfunc() is given below the view content

```
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="monthplus" id="monthplus" onClick="return monthfunc('monthplus');"  value=">>>>>>">
<input type="hidden" name="monthnum" id="monthnum" value="1">
<input type="text" name="monthname" id="monthname" value="0"  value="<? echo $month;?>" >
<input type="submit" name="monthminus" id="monthminus" onClick="return monthfunc('monthminus');" value="<<<<<<">
</td>
</tr>
```

My script is

```
function monthfunc(mnth)
{
 if(mnth == 'monthplus')
 {
  var yn = document.getElementById('monthnum').value;
  ynpo = parseInt(yn)+1;
  if(ynpo==13)
  {
   ynpo=1;
  }

 }

 else if(mnth == 'monthminus')
 {
  var yn = document.getElementById('monthnum').value;
  ynpo = parseInt(yn)-1;
  if(ynpo==0)
  {
   ynpo=12;
  }
 }
  if(ynpo ==1)
  {
    document.getElementById('monthname').value = 'january';
    document.getElementById('monthnum').value = ynpo;
    return true;
  }
  else if(ynpo ==2)
  {
    document.getElementById('monthname').value = 'february';
    document.getElementById('monthnum').value = ynpo;
    return true;
  }
  else if(ynpo ==3)
  {
    document.getElementById('monthname').value = 'March';
    document.getElementById('monthnum').value = ynpo;
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}
```

How can i replace The value with the value like january february etc..
 Actually i can change the values but cannot retain the values...
 i want to retain the values ,,,How to do that

Comment: its hard to understand ur code since all of it is in a line,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the monthname input you have two 'values'. What happens when you remove the first one?

Also, you really need to improve the structure of your function. For example, using the following array would reduce your code significantly:

```
var month=new Array(12);
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="August";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";
```

Comment: Or just `var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", ...];`

Comment: where you are mentioning the change

Comment: @udaya Instead of having all those IF statements, you can use the array to do the same in a few lines. Please open another question if you don't understand.

Comment: i replaced those if statements with the code but how can i change the month previously by clicking on the >>>>>> button i changed the month

Comment: @udaya Is your original question answered? If not then update your question with the new code. Otherwise open a new question because its not the same question as this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I exactly understand your question, but by way of an answer:

One of the input elements in your HTML snippet has two value attributes:

```
value="0"
```

and

```
value="<? echo $month;?>"
```

I would start by removing one of them.